# Changing the icon of Kivy FileChooserIconView

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I am looking for a way to change the file icon of FileChooserIconView and set it programatically. I am looking at Kivy's filechooser.py source code but cannot find where the icon is being set.

Currently, the default background color of FileChooserIconView is black and the current icon works well with that background. I need to change my app's background to white, and the current icon doesn't looks nice with white background and I also have a specific file icon that needs to be used for the white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file icon is defined in the `style.kv` file of your `Kivy` installation. And it is referenced in the `FileChooserIconView` and the `FileChooserIconLayout` classes as:

```
_ENTRY_TEMPLATE = 'FileIconEntry'
```

You can redefine that template using something like:

```
Builder.load_string('''
[FileIconEntry@Widget]:
    locked: False
    path: ctx.path
    selected: self.path in ctx.controller().selection
    size_hint: None, None

    on_touch_down: self.collide_point(*args[1].pos) and ctx.controller().entry_touched(self, args[1])
    on_touch_up: self.collide_point(*args[1].pos) and ctx.controller().entry_released(self, args[1])
    size: '100dp', '100dp'

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1 if self.selected else 0
        BorderImage:
            border: 8, 8, 8, 8
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size
            source: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/filechooser_selected'

    Image:
        size: '48dp', '48dp'
        source: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/filechooser_%s' % ('folder' if ctx.isdir else 'file')
        pos: root.x + dp(24), root.y + dp(40)
    Label:
        text: ctx.name
        text_size: (root.width, self.height)
        halign: 'center'
        shorten: True
        size: '100dp', '16dp'
        pos: root.x, root.y + dp(16)

    Label:
        text: '{}'.format(ctx.get_nice_size())
        font_size: '11sp'
        color: .8, .8, .8, 1
        size: '100dp', '16sp'
        pos: root.pos
        halign: 'center'
''')
```

The above code just duplicates the template definition from `style.kv`, but you can make any changes to the above template, and those changes will affect the `FileChooserIconView`. The `Image` is the actual icon.

Comment: Wow. this worked! I was tempted to modify the style.kv and it is good to know that I can override the [FileIconEntry@Widget] using Builder.load_string without modifying the style.kv. Thank you!